# Exe created with Pyinstaller in windows 7 is not working in xp and linux

Tags: python, linux, installation, exe, pyinstaller

I am new to python.I Have a python script for copying files from local machine to sftp location.The script will use the wxpython,pycrypto and ssh modules of python.I created an exe file by using the pyinstaller.My machine is windows 7 64-bit.I used pyinstaller 2.1 and python 2.7.6.amd 64 for creating the exe file.It's working fine in windows 7 64-bit.But it's not working in xp,win7 32-bit.In linux i used wine for executing this exe but there also it's not working.

Then i created one more exe in windows7 32-bit machine.this exe is working fine in win7 32 and 64 bit versions.but it's not working in xp.

Can anyone tell me what cpuld be the reason and how to resolve it.

I want one installer which can be installed in windows or linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such MS-Windows type "installer" is very untypical for the linux world. Linux and similar systems do allow such "wild installations", but the normal way is to use the software management systems instead and installation packages. This has a series of benefits. Few Linux users will install your "exe package". Think about that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.can you give me some names for software management systems and how to use those it will be helpful for me.

Comment: You want to deliver software for Linux systems but apparently never used one yourself? That won't work... Start by reading about the `rpm` and the `deb` package formats. Then pick a few linux distributions, install them in virtual machines and play around Iwith the systems, not with the graphical desktop). The software management system itself is not really important. It is the idea behind it you have to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Well according to [github pyinstaller site](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) there is a version for each system. Try downloading and installing it on windows XP, I suppose it will work everywhere then :P

Except linux ofcourse, I don't know about that, but I suppose pyinstaller will create installation package for you (something that you install with `pythonXXX setup.py install`). If you are more into designing your package yourself then there is great (but hard as hell) [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html).

What you have to do is build this aplication of yours on whatever system you wish to distribute it, and hold a version for each of those systems separately (there's a reason why everybody does that :P)

I know that this question is a bit old, but perhaps someone will contribute from this answer ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller does not allow cross compilation. so if you want to have an executable file you should compile your project first in Linux OS and then you may use wine in which you can compile the project to have the windows executable